# Problema con ASP.NET 2015 MVC al crear un controlador sale error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

[image: Ayudaaa]
Hola, al momento de crear un controlador o una vista me muestra este error, porque pasa esto? como lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser, que hace referencia a un assembly corrupto.

Borra ambas carpetas

1. la carpeta \bin de tu proyecto
2. La carpeta `temp` en Windows 7 debería ser `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Respuesta referida a la de [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269493/5213794) en StackOverflow en inglés.

---

También, voy a traducir la [respuesta de **Thomas**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743430/5213794) a este misma pregunta, ya que parece haber sido la solución en algunos casos

Dependiendo si estas usando X64, quizás sea necesario limpiar algunas carpetas mas.

```
%TEMP%\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Comment: no me funciono, sigue saliendo el error

Comment: tendré que crear el controlador y las vista manualmente con otros controladores y vistas que ya están